# Why does input parameter has an "object equal another object " passed into

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am confused why the input param of the code below has `{ cabinet = 'spruce', distortion = '1', volume = '0' } = {}` passed in. Does it mean all new objects created off of this class contain these params initialized? and why `{ ... } = {}` is this being used?

```
class GuitarAmp {
  constructor ({ cabinet = 'spruce', distortion = '1', volume = '0' } = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, {
      cabinet, distortion, volume
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor function is expecting you to pass in a single object with properties `cabinet`, `distortion`, and `volume`. The parameters are written this way to make all of them optional and to give all of them default values.

The reason it is written like:

```
constructor ({ cabinet = 'spruce', distortion = '1', volume = '0' } = {})
```

instead of

```
constructor ({ cabinet = 'spruce', distortion = '1', volume = '0' })
```

Is to allow it to be called with no arguments at all. The second example works fine so long as you pass in an object, but fails if you just call `new GuitarAmp()` it will fail with:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property `cabinet` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

Adding the `= {}` gives it a default empty object to destructure when nothing is passed into the constructor.